# Jena DatasetAccessor Http incompatibility

Tags: java, jena, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-jena

I'm trying to update my fuseki data end-point from Jena. 
I am using Jena DatasetAccessor Class, but i cannot compile my code.
This is the sample code i'm using :

```
public class Tutorial01 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create a simple model
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Resource johnSmith = model.createResource("http://somewhere/JohnSmith");
    johnSmith.addProperty(VCARD.FN, "John Smith");


    //Create an HTTP Data accessor
    DatasetAccessor accessor=DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("http://localhost:3030/FirstONe/data");
    //Store the model on the server
    accessor.putModel(model);
}
```

-On the last code line i receive the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.setDefaultHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:181)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:159)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:1005)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:824)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.exec(HttpOp.java:1097)
at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPut(HttpOp.java:979)
at org.apache.jena.web.DatasetGraphAccessorHTTP.doPut(DatasetGraphAccessorHTTP.java:175)
at org.apache.jena.web.DatasetGraphAccessorHTTP.httpPut(DatasetGraphAccessorHTTP.java:165)
at org.apache.jena.web.DatasetAdapter.putModel(DatasetAdapter.java:63)
at Main.Tutorial01.main(Tutorial01.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I've read online that it should be a problem with HttpCore and HttpClient incompatibles versions [(StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246979/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-def-content-charset) or HttpCore multiple versions in class path [(jena mailing list)](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201402.mbox/%3CCF2A6844.30B0F%25rvesse@dotnetrdf.org%3E) or versions that are incompatible with Jena.

I've tried with 4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.4 and none of them has worked.

Someone knows which are the right version to use or has solved a similar problem ?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Eiother use the jars provided in the Jena download (the binary zip comes with the right Apache Common Http jars) or, better, use maven (gradle, ant/ivy,...) to manage the dependencies and they will pull in the right version.  The published POM name the right version if you want to browse those.