# DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET Error

Tags: spring, http, apache-storm

In my storm topology am getting below error. frequently i am getting below issue please help here.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.setDefaultHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:175) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:158) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:448) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:309) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:286) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:851) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at com.trinity.sensors.LocationName.getPlaceName(LocationName.java:77) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at com.trinity.sensors.ItmsVehicleDataBolt.execute(ItmsVehicleDataBolt.java:126) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6713$tuple_action_fn__6715.invoke(executor.clj:684) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__6636.invoke(executor.clj:431) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1319.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6713$fn__6726$fn__6777.invoke(executor.clj:813) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227.jar:0.10.0.2.4.3.0-227]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
2018-05-29 09:21:27.164 b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll refer you to [java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246979/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-def-content-charset). Some of your dependencies (likely the Apache HttpClient ones) are the wrong version.

Try running `mvn dependency:tree` in the root of your topology project. You'll likely find some versions of the HttpClient libraries with versions that don't match up. The fix would be to add a `<dependencyManagement>` section to your pom where you set the versions for the HttpClient libraries so they are the same.